# Django: Treat form field before validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that has the following datetime field:

**Forms.py**

```
class FormBacktest(forms.Form):
    dateStart = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date Start")

    def to_python(self, dateStart):
        return serialize_datetime(dateStart)
```

When the user submits the form, `dateStart` is a string that has the following value: `12 January, 2020`. I want to serialize the field on the backend side before validation to get `datetime.datetime(2020, 01, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. To do so, I've found in the documentation that the method `save_<Field>` won't work, since it's executed after `all_clean_data`.

I could also use the method `to_python`, but it is not exactly what i'm looking for :

> This method accepts the raw value from the widget and returns the
>   converted value.

Even so, I've tried to use it, but the function is never called. My view looks like this:

**Views.py**

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       backtestForm = FormBacktest(request.POST)
       if backtestForm.is_valid():
            # blabla
```

What is the best strategy to treat the data before validation?

Comment: But form makes serialization for you. It's return datetime object after you call `is_valid`. Or you want to do something else? Could you please add more detail or example?

Comment: edited, the object passed is a `str`  with the value `12 January, 2020` but i need to serialize it to `datetime.datetime(2020, 01, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use DateTimeField's [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField.input_formats) argument instead:

```
class FormBacktest(forms.Form):
    dateStart = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date Start", input_formats=["%d %B, %Y"])
```

You can find datetime formats description [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).